# how to make countdoun timer in java script which should not reset on page reload

Tags: javascript, html, timer

i have used this code it working but when i refresh the page it reset to initial stage, i want it should continue after page reload also here is code i have used

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Timer</title>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="counter"><input type="text" size="8" name="d2"></form> 

<script> 
<!-- 
// 
var milisec=0 
var seconds=30 
document.counter.d2.value='30' 

function display()
{ 
   if (milisec<=0)
   { 
       milisec=9 
       seconds-=1 
   } 
   if (seconds<=-1)
   { 
       milisec=0 
       seconds+=1 
   } 
   else 
      milisec-=1 
   document.counter.d2.value=seconds+"."+milisec 
   setTimeout("display()",100) 
} 
display()
--> 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: use cookie or localstorage for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save current seconds value in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) (or maybe `sessionStorage`) this is the easiest way to persist the value:

```
var milisec = 0
var seconds = localStorage.seconds || 30;
document.counter.d2.value = seconds;

function display() {

    if (milisec <= 0) {
        milisec = 9
        seconds -= 1
    }

    if (seconds <= -1) {
        milisec = 0
        seconds += 1
    } else milisec -= 1

    localStorage.seconds = seconds;
    document.counter.d2.value = seconds + "." + milisec;

    if (seconds > 0 || (seconds == 0 && milisec > 0)) {
        setTimeout(display, 100);
    }
}

display();
```

Also note, that you probably want to stop interval when timer reaches `0` value, so I added `seconds > 0 || (seconds == 0 && milisec > 0)` part.

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6zL5eL2z/1/